# Upgrading from react-hook-form 6 to 7.33

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, ref

```
inputRef={(ref: HTMLInputElement | null) => {
          if (ref) {
            register(ref, {
              required: true,
              pattern: /^[a-z'\-\s]+$/i
            });
            if (refInputName) refInputName.current = ref;
          }
        }}
```

How do I change this code, I'm new to the react-hook-form. Thanks